# FIWARE - IDAS: Issue with registered device

Tags: fiware, agent, fiware-orion

I’m having problems with the IDAS Iotagent. Using the MQTT Ultralight agent, depending on how I register a device, when the agent receives a reading the iotagent service crashes and the related entity into the context broker is not updated.

The correct behaviour is the next one. If create a service:

```
curl -X POST 172.21.0.23:8090/iot/services \
-i  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: red_entrada _1" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /Prueba" \
-d '{
    "services": [
    {
        "apikey": "pass_1", 
        "cbroker": "http://172.21.0.23:1026", 
        "entity_type": "disp_entrada_1", 
        "resource": "/iot/mqtt"
    }]}'
```

... and a device, establishing the incoming attributes and a name for each one of them:

```
curl -X POST 172.21.0.23:8090/iot/devices \
-i  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: red_entrada _1" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /Prueba" \
-d '{
"devices":[
{
    "device_id": "AC_2", 
    "entity_name":"disp_entrada_1:AC_2",
    "protocol":"PDI-IoTA-MQTT-UltraLight", 
    "entity_type": "disp_entrada_1", 
    "timezone": "Europe/Madrid", 
    "attributes": [ 
    {
        "object_id": "LUX", 
        "name": "LUX_1", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "LUM", 
        "name": "LUM_1",
        "type": "string" }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "HUMB", 
        "name": "HUMB_1", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "TCB", 
        "name": "TCB_1", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "IN_TEMP", 
        "name": "IN_TEMP_1", 
        "type": "string" }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "BAT", 
        "name": "BAT_1", 
        "type": "string" 
    } 
]}]}'
```

As a result, a new entity is created into the context broker, and as the readings arrive to the agent, this entity is updated:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "id" : "disp_entrada_1:AC_2",
                "type" : "disp_entrada_1",
                "servicePath" : "/Prueba"
        },
        "attrNames" : [
                "TimeInstant",
                "LUX_1",
                "LUM_1",
                "HUMB_1",
                "TCB_1",
                "IN_TEMP_1",
                "BAT_1"
        ],
        "attrs" : {
                "TimeInstant" : {
                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.810465Z",
                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                        "creDate" : 1457943015,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                },
                "LUX_1" : {
                        "value" : "464.000",
                        "type" : "string",
                        "md" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "TimeInstant",
                                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.687585Z"
                                }
                        ],
                        "creDate" : 1457943103,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                },
                "LUM_1" : {
                        "value" : "2.694",
                        "type" : "string",
                        "md" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "TimeInstant",
                                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.718131Z"
                                }
                        ],
                        "creDate" : 1457943103,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                },
                "HUMB_1" : {
                        "value" : "38.7",
                        "type" : "string",
                        "md" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "TimeInstant",
                                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.748719Z"
                                }
                        ],
                        "creDate" : 1457943103,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                },
                "TCB_1" : {
                        "value" : "21.31",
                        "type" : "string",
                        "md" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "TimeInstant",
                                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.779327Z"
                                }
                        ],
                        "creDate" : 1457943103,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                },
                "IN_TEMP_1" : {
                        "value" : "21.00",
                        "type" : "string",
                        "md" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "TimeInstant",
                                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.810465Z"
                                }
                        ],
                        "creDate" : 1457943103,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                },
                "BAT_1" : {
                        "value" : "97",
                        "type" : "string",
                        "md" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "TimeInstant",
                                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                                        "value" : "2016-03-14T08:11:49.230590Z"
                                }
                        ],
                        "creDate" : 1457943103,
                        "modDate" : 1457943109
                }
        },
        "creDate" : 1457943015,
        "modDate" : 1457943109
}
```

The problem arises when I register a new DEVICE and I use as the name for the attributes the same value of the "object_id" (name of the attribute into the incoming MQTT data. Surely on this scenario it's not necessary to register a DEVICE). For example:

```
curl -X POST 172.21.0.23:8090/iot/devices \
-i  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: red_entrada_2" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /Prueba" \
-d '{
"devices":[
{
    "device_id": "AC_2", 
    "entity_name":"disp_entrada_1:AC_2",
    "protocol":"PDI-IoTA-MQTT-UltraLight", 
    "entity_type": "disp_entrada_1", 
    "timezone": "Europe/Madrid", 
    "attributes": [ 
    { 
        "object_id": "LUX", 
        "name": "LUX", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "LUM", 
        "name": "LUM", 
        "type": "string"
    },
    { 
        "object_id": "HUMB", 
        "name": "HUMB", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "TCB", 
        "name": "TCB", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "IN_TEMP", 
        "name": "IN_TEMP", 
        "type": "string" 
    }, 
    { 
        "object_id": "BAT", 
        "name": "BAT", 
        "type": "string" 
    } 
]}] }'
```

On that case a new entity is created into the context broker too, but when the readings arrive the entity is not updated and the IoTAgent service crashes. Entity status:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "id" : " disp_entrada_1:AC_2",
                "type" : " disp_entrada_1",
                "servicePath" : "/Prueba"
        },
        "attrNames" : [
                "TimeInstant"
        ],
        "attrs" : {
                "TimeInstant" : {
                        "type" : "ISO8601",
                        "creDate" : 1457948167,
                        "modDate" : 1457948167,
                        "value" : "2016-03-14T09:36:07.432814Z"
                }
        },
        "creDate" : 1457948167,
        "modDate" : 1457948167
}
```

I can’t see any logic on this behaviour. If I don't register beforehand the device, the entity will be created automatically and the attributes will have as the name the value of the "object_id" field (that was what I was attempting to do on the second example).

¿Can it be due to an issue on the agent or manager installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is a bug, when you associate a parameter "t" to be translated to the same ("t") then it results in a infinite loop.

The best solution is not to ask for any translation and then it will be kept as the original ("t").

In the next versions, this bug will be fixed.

Thanks for using IDAS and sorry for our late reply!